# Parallel resistors, why? (Basic electronics)

Tags: current-source, diagram

I'm curious as to why R1+R3 is parallel to R4 and not R2? could someone please explain this to me. 
What rules are R2 violating that makes it non-parallel (and what makes R4 parallel)?
Thanks.

What i was thinking: `(R1+R3)//(R4+R2)`

Correct expression: `(R1+R3)//R4 + R2`

[image: circuit]

Comment: (R1+R3)//R4. R2 is in series with [(R1+R3)//R4]. Remove that confusing ground symbol. Why is it there? You can define ground at any point you want. Remove it. It is there to trick you.

Comment: @user134429 thanks, i think i got it. Since the current is generated by E, it first splits at point A, i now see why it is parallel with R4 and not R2. Yeah, i was really confused by that. I guess that was what my teacher wanted.

Comment: Move the ground to the negative terminal of the battery and show it to your foxy teacher.

Comment: @user134429 haha will do that. However, now that i've got your attention. If i were to calculate the potential in point A. How would i go about doing that here? KVL according to my teacher is: `-R2*I + E - Uab` why :(?

Comment: take the ground point as zero potential not the battery's negative terminal. because he defines ground at that point in your diagram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the ground from the schematic, and it should be obvious that R1+R3 is in parallel is R4.

Remember that ground is just the one point in a circuit we declare the 0 V reference to implicitly measure other voltages relative to.  In this case, no current can flow in or out of the ground connection since there is no other ground connection anywhere in this circuit.  Since no current flows thru the connection, you can remove it for the purpose of analyzing the circuit.

Answer (score 0):

For any circuit to be in parallel with another circuit, both circuits need to start at the same node, and end at some common other node, with no other branches out of that path where current is flowing.

In your schematic you can see that R1 and R3 are in series from point A to point B, and R4 is also connected across the same points.

But, what about the branch to ground between R1 and R3?

In this instance, since that ground is not connected anywhere else in the schematic, it basically is not a branch out of the circuit, since no current will flow down that path under normal circumstances. You can therefore ignore it in your analysis.

As such, R1 + R3 can be said to be in parallel with R4.

R2 is in series with the battery and though one end is at node B, the other end is not at node A. It therefore does not meet the criteria for being in parallel.

However, R2 plus the battery, IS in parallel with R1+R3 and R4.